# Using ckeditor5-typing package in CKEditor

Tags: angular, typescript, ckeditor5

I'm trying to develop a soft keyboard using CKEditor. This requires that I transform text upon input (completed) and sometimes need to delete a key (where I'm struggling). My current code is as follows:

```
ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
        .then(editor => {
            console.log( editor );
            editor.editing.view.document.on( 'keydown', ( event, data ) => {

                var keyPressed = data.domEvent.key;
                //getMappedCharacter returns a map
                //String newKey -> value of the keyPressed
                //Boolean deleteKey -> Whether the previous character should be deleted
                var mappedCode = getMappedCharacter(keyPressed);
                console.log('mc', mappedCode)

                if (mappedCode.newKey != keyPressed) {
                    data.preventDefault();
                    event.stop();


                    if(mappedCode.deleteKey){
                      //  WHERE I'M STRUGGLING
                      // Trying to delete the latest character inserted (where my cursor is located). 
                    }

                    editor.model.change( writer => {
                        writer.insertText( mappedCode.newKey, editor.model.document.selection.getFirstPosition() );
                    } );
                }

            })
        })
        .catch( error => {
            console.error( error );
        } );
```

I'm currently trying to use the ckeditor5-typing package's Delete command with CKEditor5 on an Angular/Typescript project. Documentation says I should include the Typing package in the Plugins like so

```
    ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
            plugins: [ Essentials, Paragraph, Bold, Italic ],
            toolbar: [ 'bold', 'italic' ]
        } )
```

However, when I do that, I get the following error in the console:

[image: console error]

When I enter `document.querySelector('#editor')` in the console, I get the following:

`<textarea _ngcontent-c1 dir=​"rtl" id=​"editor" name=​"content">​</textarea>​`

So I am not sure sure why it is showing me a null error in the console.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

What this code does:

```
ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
        plugins: [ Typing ]
    }  )
```

Is that it loads **only** the Typing plugin. At the same time, as I can see by the warnings, you use a CKEditor 5 build which has a pre-configured toolbar (you can find an example [here](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/blob/master/src/ckeditor.js)). So, what happens is that the editor loads only a single plugin but it tries to add multiple (inexisting) buttons to the toolbar. Hence, warnings are logged.

What surprises me, though, is that you're trying to enable this plugin. First of all, it's enabled in all types of editor builds. Second, you need also enable other plugins to see anything. E.g. the editor will not render any content if you won't enable at least the [`Paragraph`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_paragraph_paragraph-Paragraph.html) plugin.

PS. Make sure to read https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/development/installing-plugins.html because it seems that you're trying to add plugins to a build while plugins can only be added when the editor is built from the source.

Comment: When I do it the formal way, I get a cannot read attribute of null - however, `document.querySelector( '#editor' )` does return something. How may I access the Typing package/Delete command?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You need to be more specific what you did, what happened and what you want to achieve.

Comment: I've updated my question to be clearer - I hope that helps you help me :)

Comment: You mixed so many things in the question that I'm still completely confused. You pasted a code with a "WHERE I'M STRUGGLING" comment which is completely unrelated to the error that you get and to the textarea that is logged to the console. You're trying to tackle at least 3 issues at the same time while you should work on them one by one.

Comment: The first problem you need to solve is why the editor does not start (the error that you get) and it has nothing to do with "Using ckeditor5-typing package in CKEditor". It's caused by incomplete webpack configuration. Open a new question for that and we may be able to help you.